# Combining tables SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

- Table 1: LocID, Prod_ID, Metric_ID, Metric_Data
- Table 2: LocID, Metric_ID, Metric_Data

I need a Result Table as:

- LocID
- Prod_ID
- Metric_ID
- Metric_Data with the following conditions being met:

  1. When Metric_ID's match, the Metric_Data will be added
  2. When Metric_ID do not match, the relevant Metric_Data will be shown (meaning the one which has value)
  3. Please note only a some common and some different Metric_ID's exist in Table 1 and Table 2.

How do you generate this 3rd table? I have tried all kinds of joins - full, left, right, etc.

Comment: a. "When Metric_ID's match, the Metric_Data will be added" - There are two metric_data fields.  Which one should be added?
Sounds like a case statement would be helpful here.

Comment: Are the two tables only related by Metric_ID? I.e., is "LocID" the PK of their respective tables and thus not related to each other or is LocID also a joining column?

Comment: related by LocID and Metric_ID; the primary keys are LocID, Metric_ID for one table and LocID, Prod_ID, Metric_ID for the other table. The final table should contain all the four columns and Prod_ID cannot be null or empty in the final table

Comment: What would help more than anything is some sample inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: Let me explain: Assume we are manufacturing products at different locations. There is a direct cost of the product (Prod_ID) and there is an indirect cost which is common to all products being manufactured at that location (LocID). The costs are broken down into various items (Metric_ID and Metric_Data). I have to report on final cost (Direct Cost + Indirect Cost) by Cost Items. Some Cost Items are common to both the tables and some are specific to each table. My final table has to include all the cost items for the product at a location, i.e. it has to have LocID, Prod_ID which cannot be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

```
select
    A.LocID,
    A.Prod_ID,
    B.Metric_ID,
    coalesce(C.Metric_Data + D.Metric_Data, C.Metric_Data, D.Metric_Data) Metric_Data
from (
    select LocID, Prod_ID from table1 group by LocID, Prod_ID) A
inner join (
    select LocID, Metric_ID from table1 group by LocID
    union
    select LocID, Metric_ID from table2 group by LocID) B on A.LocID = B.LocID
left join table1 C on C.LocID = A.LocID and C.Prod_ID = A.Prod_ID and C.Metric_ID = B.Metric_ID
left join table2 D on D.LocID = A.LocID and D.Metric_ID = B.Metric_ID
```

Notes:

- A: produces all the location and ProdID combinations
- B: produces, for each location, all the possible MetricIDs from both tables
- C and D: left joins to the data tables to get the Metric Data
- Coalesce: returns either C + D, or if one of them is null, return the other

---

```
select
    coalesce(a.LocID, b.LocID) LocID,
    a.Prod_ID,
    coalesce(a.Metric_ID, b.Metric_ID) Metric_ID,
    coalesce(a.Metric_Data + b.Metric_Data, a.Metric_Data, b.Metric_Data) Metric_Data
from table1 a
full outer join table2 b
    on a.LocID = b.LocID and a.Metric_ID = b.Metric_ID
```

This assumes

1. You are matching by the tuple (LocID, Metric_ID)
2. It is possible for either A or B not to have (LocID,Metric_ID) that exists in the other
3. The result of Metric_Data is either A+B (if both exist), or A or B if only one exists for a (LocID, Metric_ID) combination

Comment: Richard, you are almost there - can I get the Prod_ID for all the records in the final table - the idea is that the final metric data is for the product and is the sum of the product and location. So the final table will have LocID, Prod_ID, Metric_ID, Metric_Data as you have brought out but Prod_ID will not be empty - it will take a value always and no data row of the combined tables (both) will be left out. Your assumptions are correct.

Comment: The query should work naturally, if there is ALWAYS a record on the A-side (to supply ProdID) - but if that condition is true, I would use LEFT JOIN instead of FULL JOIN. Now if (LocID,MetricID) exists in B but NOT in A, then where can ProdID come from??

Comment: Consider it like this - I have a table by Prod_ID which has certain metric data. I have another table which has common metric data and is not for a particular Prod_ID. The common link is the LocID between the two tables. However, MetricID may not be all available in both the tables. But my final table needs all the MetricIDs as you got but it also has to be for the Prod_ID. What you have got is almost a union but I lost some rows - do now know how. Thanks Richard for helping me out.

Comment: So when I add the Common metric row to the Prod_ID metric row - I get the final metric for the Prod_ID. That is why, my final table needs to contain the Prod_ID and the metrics for the products. For example - to manufacture - their is a direct cost for the product and there is a indirect cost (which is common to all products). However, the total cost of a product is its direct cost + indirect cost. I have to report the total cost of the product. The LocID is where it is being manufactured. And MetricID are various cost items - not always present in each case. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much Richard - you are awesome - wonderful and quick response. Just one more thing - any way to speed it up - takes a while for the results to come - I have a less than 5,000 records in total between the two tables. Thanks once again!